# How to combine multiple javascript strings into one while maintaining position

Tags: jquery, string, replace, position, append

I have the following situation. In order to serve a specific URL to a visitor, the user must click 3 options in a total of three lists. The objects he/she clicks contain a data-attribute. These 3 attributes make up an URL:

- A product
- A topic
- A device

HTML code:

```
<div class="choice-list">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-href="productone"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="producttwo"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="productthree"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-href="topicone"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="topictwo"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="topicthree"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
    <ul>
        <li><span data-href="deviceone"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="devicetwo"></span></li>
        <li><span data-href="devicethree"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So the final URL could be: *productone-topictwo-devicethree*. I managed to make a rather simple script for this, but I find it hard to remember the position of each string. Because if the user generates the URL *productone-topictwo-devicethree* and he edits it in a way that *topictwo* needs to be *topicthree*, my current script will just append the new value.

```
$j(".product-support-steps .choice-list").each(function() {
    var $currentList = $j(this);
    $currentList.each(function() {
        $currentList.find('li').click(function() {

            //Get URL params ...
            var $urlParam = $j(this).data('href');
            $j('.finalurl').val(function(_, val) {
                if (val.match($urlParam)) {
                    return val.replace($urlParam, '');
                }
                return val + $urlParam;
            });

            var $finalUrl = $j(".finalurl").val();
            console.log($finalUrl);
        });

    });
});
```

If anyone could help me finalize this script so the 3 list values can be added and removed and remember their positions, you're doing gods work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these code. You just need to make small changes on your existing code and everything works like a charm.

HTML

```
<div class="choice-list">
<ul>
<li><span data-index='0' data-href="productone">productone</span></li>
<li><span data-index='0' data-href="producttwo">producttwo</span></li>
<li><span data-index='0' data-href="productthree">productthree</span></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
<ul>
<li><span data-index='1' data-href="topicone">topicone</span></li>
<li><span data-index='1' data-href="topictwo">topictwo</span></li>
<li><span data-index='1' data-href="topicthree">topicthree</span></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
<ul>
<li><span data-index='2' data-href="deviceone">deviceone</span></li>
<li><span data-index='2' data-href="devicetwo">devicetwo</span></li>
<li><span data-index='2' data-href="devicethree">devicethree</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

With respect to this HTML below is the JavaScript code:

```
  var urlArray = ['','',''];
  $('.choice-list').find('li').click(function() {
            //gets the URL text
            var href = $(this).find('span').attr('data-href'),
                //determines the index on the array where the URL text will 
                //be inserted
                index = $(this).find('span').attr('data-index');
                //insert the URL text in specified index of array
                urlArray[index] = href;
                //convert the array to the specified URL format with hyphen
                var url = urlArray.toString().replace(/,/g,'-');
                console.log(url);
 });
```

Here is also a working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qos2oyes/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I was getting too deep in my problem i didn't notice the logical outcome.

Comment: Never mind, if you really got help from this answer please do not forget to upvote it as others will take it as a properly accepted answer by you.

Comment: Let me know if you have more queries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go that complicated it. just put a data attribute selected in parent and whichever option is selected store in the attribute
and at the end join the values and send. more validations can be put in palace i just did the basic idea.

```js
$(".choice-list li span").click(function() {
          var val = $(this).data('href');
          $(this).closest('.choice-list').attr('data-selected',val) 
});

$("#getfinal").click(function(){
  var url = [];
   $(".choice-list").each(function(){
      if($(this).data('selected'))
        url.push($(this).data('selected'))
   });
   if(url.length >= 3)
   {
      alert(url.join('-'));
    }else{
     alert("select all three options");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-selected="" class="choice-list">
  <p>click to choose</p>
    <ul>
    <li><span data-href="productone">a</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="producttwo">b</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="productthree">c</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div data-selected="" class="choice-list">
    <p>click to choose</p>
    <ul>
    <li><span data-href="topicone">a</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="topictwo">b</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="topicthree">c</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div data-selected="" class="choice-list">
    <p>click to choose</p>
    <ul>
    <li><span data-href="deviceone">a</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="devicetwo">b</span></li>
    <li><span data-href="devicethree">c</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<button id="getfinal">FINAL</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object `url` and assign the properties `product`, `topic` and `device` when clicking on a `li` element. I added a `data-choice` property on each `ul` corresponding to each choice.

Clicking on an element adds the property in the object `url`, re-clicking on the same element removes the property from the object.

Then when the url is complete (3 choices made), it displays the full URL.

Please try the following snippet:

```js
var url = {};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".choice-list").on("click", "li", function () {
        var prop = $(this).closest("ul").data("choice");
        var value = $(this).find("span").data("href");

        if (url.hasOwnProperty(prop) && url[prop] == value) {
            delete url[prop];
        } else {
            url[prop] = value;
        }

        console.log(url);

        if (url.hasOwnProperty("product") && url.hasOwnProperty("topic") && url.hasOwnProperty("device")) {
            console.log("URL complete: " + constructUrl(url));
        }
    });
});

function constructUrl(url) {
    return url["product"] + "-" + url["topic"] + "-" + url["device"];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="choice-list">
    <ul data-choice="product">
        <li><span data-href="productone">Product 1</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="producttwo">Product 2</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="productthree">Product 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
    <ul data-choice="topic">
        <li><span data-href="topicone">Topic 1</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="topictwo">Topic 2</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="topicthree">Topic 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="choice-list">
    <ul data-choice="device">
        <li><span data-href="deviceone">Device 1</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="devicetwo">Device 2</span></li>
        <li><span data-href="devicethree">Device 3</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```